# Find and delete desktop.ini files in every folder on a drive using a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, hidden, delete-file

I want to find and delete every desktop.ini and Recycle Bin.BIN file on a network drive, H:, using a windows batch file. I currently have this:

```
@echo About to delete all desktop.ini and Recycle Bin.BIN files from H:, press Ctrl+C to cancel or Enter to continue.
@pause
@H:
@for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /s /b /x /A:H ^| find "desktop.ini"`) do del /A:H "%%i"
@for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /s /b /x /A:RH ^| find "Recycle Bin.BIN"`) do del /A:RH "%%i"
@echo Deleting complete, press any key to exit.
@pause
```

Which works but for any file in a sub-folder with a space in the name it fails with a "cannot find file" error.  Any suggestions how to fix that?

Answer (score 16):

solution that worked for me was

create bat file "delete_all_desktop_ini.bat"
with

```
del /s /q /f /a ".\desktop.ini"
```

put it in a folder and run it

it will delete all desktop inis in current directory and sub directories of this file.

i put it in a project folder that is in google drive

Answer (score 9):

Give this a test:

I've altered the recycle bin name to what I see here in Windows 8.
The name changes with different versions of Windows.

```
@echo off
del /s /q /f /a "h:\desktop.ini" 
del /s /q /f /a "h:\$Recycle.Bin\*.*"
```

Comment: Or `del /s /q /f /a desktop.ini` is the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because by default space is a delimiter for the `for` command, but you can change this using the `delims` option. If you pick a character that won't ever appear in a file path then it should work fine:

```
@echo About to delete all desktop.ini and Recycle Bin.BIN files from H:, press Ctrl+C to cancel or Enter to continue.
@pause
@H:
@for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%i in (`dir /s /b /x /A:H ^| find "desktop.ini"`) do del /A:H "%%i"
@for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%i in (`dir /s /b /x /A:RH ^| find "Recycle Bin.BIN"`) do del /A:RH "%%i"
@echo Deleting complete, press any key to exit.
@pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r "H:\" %%a in (desktop.ini $Recycle.Bin) do if exist "%%~fa" echo del /f "%%~fa"
```

Try it, to make it working remove `echo` from the script.

Answer (score 0):

del /s /q /f /a ".\desktop.ini"

it should works as charm
save file .bat
put it in any folder
it will delete ini files in folders and sub folders